# codeigniter avoid appending quotes to a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm new to codeigniter. The problem I'm facing is that I'm storing a value in database and codeigniter append single quotes around my value and if I've single quotes around my value the SQL server doesn't store it and prompts error.

I'm actually getting data from a table like this

```
$this->db->select('priority, address, shape.STAsText() shape');
$this->db->from('POI');
$this->db->where("OBJECTID = '$id'");
$poi = $this->db->get()->row();
```

The next thing is that I've to manipulate the value of a column **shape** before inserting this data into another table. For this I get the `shape` attribute of `$poi` object and manipulate it like below

```
$poi->shape =  "geometry::STGeomFromText('$poi->shape',4326)";
```

Now, when I try to save this `$poi` to database like below

```
$this->db->insert('poi_logs',$poi)
```

The query looks like

```
INSERT INTO "poi_logs" ("priority", "address", "shape")
    VALUES
(6, 'Street 40 Margalla Town Phase 2 Islamabad', 'geometry::STGeomFromText(''POINT (73.106225740025934 33.668451250424937)'',4326)');
```

You can see it has appended the single quotes around the `shape` value and also added single quotes where ever the signle quotes comes inside value. I want to avoid this. I want the statement like below

```
INSERT INTO "poi_logs" ("priority", "address", "shape")
    VALUES
(6, 'Street 40 Margalla Town Phase 2 Islamabad', geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (73.106225740025934 33.668451250424937)',4326));
```

I've looked around but couldn't find any solution. If anyone knows, please help me

**Edited**

if I use

```
$poi->shape =  $this->db->escape("geometry::STGeomFromText('$poi->shape',4326)");
```

the resultant query looks like

```
INSERT INTO "poi_logs" ("priority", "address", "shape" )
    VALUES
(6, 'Street 40 Margalla Town Phase 2 Islamabad', '''geometry::STGeomFromText(''''POINT (73.106225740025934 33.668451250424937)'''',4326)''')
```

Comment: pretty sure this is occurring because your values being extracted have ( ) in it and this messes with PHP, its needing to escape these details... Can you save without the ()'s? Have you tried outputting the values to where you need to and see if its actually an issue when you display it?

Comment: no, I need to append `()` within the value

Comment: @RejoanulAlam .. Yes, I've tried this but no success. I've updated the question, please see if this was the way, you were saying to try.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam ..  yes exactly, you're write. I need to use both `( ' ' )` brackets and quotes in my value

Comment: @RejoanulAlam .. waiting for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$poi->address = $this->db->escape($poi->address);
$poi->shape =  "geometry::STGeomFromText('$poi->shape',4326)";
$this->db->set($poi, '', false);
$this->db->insert('poi_logs');
```